# Xcode: utility application template displays navigation bar at the bottom

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar, autolayout

I'm trying to update a universal app based on Utility Application Template but iPhone's version displays the navigation bar on the flipside view at the bottom, while the iPad's version works okay.

I didn't (consciously) touch the piece of code that rules the flipside view controller, but unchecked "Use Autolayout" to make it compatible with iOS 5.

How can I get the navigation bar back to the upper part of the screen?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I "commented" the followin line of code and it's working now:

```
self.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
```